# Problems publishing a website in GitHub. GitHub Pages is different on my end. Can't follow along tutorials

Tags: github, publish

I have a problem with publishing a website via GitHub. When I try to follow along a website like this: https://progate.com/docs/github-pages, in the step 5 (Publishing your webpage), I don't manage to see what the author of the tutorial sees in GitHub Pages (this: [GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRj71.png)) but rather i see this: [Pages in my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cYo5.png) (and when clicking on "add a domain" I see this [pages/add a verified domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIJrE.png)). What should I do after uploading my repository in GitHub, to publish a website via GitHub if I see what I see instead of what the tutorial says I should see (when going to Pages in GitHub)?

Could you please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are going to the wrong place. It looks like you are going to the "Pages" tab of your profile, not your repository. Make sure you go to your repository first, then go to "Settings", then you will find the "Pages" tab on the right, like this:

[image: Screenshot]